# ConfigParser library not working when using with python3

Tags: python, configparser

I am using and importing ConfigParaser

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('Config.properties')
timeout_val=config.get('Section', 'commandtimeout')
```

and install it using,

```
pip install ConfigParser
```

While running the python script getting below mention error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "system_offline.py", line 41, in <module>
    import ConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

Now, my question is if run the same program using python 2.7 at the same system, above import statement works with out issue.

Wondering what needs to be done for this program to run with python3?

Edit: While using python 2.7 it is working but with python3, i am getting above mention error.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: python3 --version
Python 3.5.2

Comment: I edited the question. On the path i was using with python, now getting error with python3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ConfigParser` module was [renamed to `configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#library-changes) in Python 3.0.

Comment: and what to used for RawConfigParser? as shown above in question?

Comment: [The `configparser` module still contains a `RawConfigParser` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#rawconfigparser-objects).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3, this will work, the module was renamed

import configparser
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()